# Shortcut to open xfce4-terminal and run 'history' command on Xubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: bash, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, history

I'm trying to set a keyboard shortcut to open xfce4-terminal and run history(command) and keeping terminal open, but so far no avail, I read some tutorials then I tried ***xfce4-terminal -e "/bin/bash -c history; exec bash"*** , but nothing happens (I noticed the terminal opens and closes quickly) how to get it working? thks, vladi
OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable history separately in a non-interactive shell:

```
xfce4-terminal --hold -x bash -c 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; history'
```

[Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5701/111181)

Comment: Thanks, that's it, finally this command works:), I have waited almost an year for it.:))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `--hold` ?

According to their [doc](https://www.mankier.com/1/xfce4-terminal), this should work

`xfce4-terminal --command "command_with_args" --hold`

In your case

`xfce4-terminal --command "history" --hold`

Comment: not working, I got a window displaying **Fail to execute child process no such a file or directory** I think the history command is a INTERNAL LINUX command and should be treated differently, but so far I don't know how to fix the shortcut.